# Calculate average of 2nd column based on the 1st col in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a input log file like this:

```
CLASS:CLASS1, CREATE_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:06, VALID_AFTER_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, EVAL_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, SUCCESS:true, TIME_TAKEN:1842
CLASS:CLASS1, CREATE_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:06, VALID_AFTER_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, EVAL_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, SUCCESS:true, TIME_TAKEN:1842
CLASS:CLASS2, CREATE_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:06, VALID_AFTER_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, EVAL_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, SUCCESS:true, TIME_TAKEN:1842
CLASS:CLASS1, CREATE_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:06, VALID_AFTER_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, EVAL_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, SUCCESS:true, TIME_TAKEN:1842
CLASS:CLASS2, CREATE_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:06, VALID_AFTER_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, EVAL_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, SUCCESS:true, TIME_TAKEN:1842
CLASS:CLASS1, CREATE_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:06, VALID_AFTER_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, EVAL_TIME:30-Dec-2015 00:00:12, SUCCESS:true, TIME_TAKEN:1842
```

I want to calculate the average time taken by each class.
For example I want the **output** like this:

```
CLASS1 5.5
CLASS2 13
```

I am using the following to Extract the *class* **name** and the **time**, but not able to calculate the avg.

```
awk -F'[,:]' '{print $25 " " $41;}' modified_01.log | sort
```

**Output:**

```
CLASS:CLASS1 10
CLASS:CLASS1 1
CLASS:CLASS2 9
CLASS:CLASS1 10
CLASS:CLASS2 17
CLASS:CLASS1 1
```

Comment: associative array, thousands of questions on here asking the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe your output to this awk:

```
awk -F '[: ]' '{a[$2]++; s[$2]+=$3} END{
        for (i in s) printf "%s%s%.1f\n", i, OFS, s[i]/a[i]}'
CLASS1 5.5
CLASS2 13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

pipe the input to the below command. Then you will get the required results.

```
awk '{if(a[$1]){a[$1]=a[$1]+$2; count[$1]=count[$1]+1}else {a[$1]=$2;count[$1]=1}}END{for (i in a)print i"\t"a[i]/count[i];}' | cut -f2 -d":"
```